# When using react-router, I refresh and lose my state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, frontend

I'm passing previously fetched data, through location.state to subsequent components. That works fine, however, if the user hits refresh my history, and location state objects are wiped out. I can see that this is the intended functionality. My question is, am I supposed to be using redux to keep this data persisting? If that's the case, I lose a lot of the benefits of react-router in my opinion. How are people handling state when using react-router?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think using redux for data persistence negates benefits of react router, but basically you can either save the data into browser's local storage, then check that when the component mounts to see if data is already there (and whether stored data is too out of data and needs to be re-fetched). Or you can use redux, save the data in the store and use a module like `redux-persist` to persist the store when refreshing and the link

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the states as [props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route), or save it in [localStorage](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/) for a wider access.

Comment: Correct, I just have a data flow, of about 4 steps, if you refresh on step 4, or navigate directly to step 4, nothing works because the state is undefined. That's just how state works, it's cleared on refresh. I solved it by just routing back to step 1 in the event state is undefined.

Comment: I see.What would i do is i will save it on sessionState then, so that in the initial state and the variable that holds the state is undefined, it will just get the one you saved from the sessionState.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to persist the data, you should store your data on database or localstorage for an example. And when you refresh the page, you can fetch your data from the store.

If your component is class base component you can use componentDidMount for fetching the data and set the state or redux.

If your component is functional component you can use useEffect for the same scenario.( react version should be greater than 16.8)

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Data can be stored locally on the browser with the `localStorage()` function. The data can also be sent to the next component by using the `this.props.history.push` function.
In the end, I chose to save the data in the browser's local storage as I wanted to pass and access the data in a child react component and being able to refresh the page. By saving the data in the local storage the data stay whereas any using the `history.push()` functionality to pass the data, the data is deleted after hitting the refresh button.

Below there is an example in case you want to pass the content of the `pseudo` variable in the child component.

```js
localStorage.setItem('pseudo', this.state.pseudo)

OR 

this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/NextPage', 
  data: { pseudo: this.state.pseudo }
});
```

To get the data in the child component **NextPage.js** you can use the following code:

```js
props.location.data.pseudo

OR

localStorage.getItem("pseudo")
```

Answer (score -3):

React-router isn't concerned with state management. To manage state, use Redux or other solutions like Xstate. To persist data on the client you may look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Right, but how can you pass state through react-router, without using history or location state?